# Incorrect year passed to dayGridMonth header in dayHeaderContent options

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

The `dayHeaderContent` and `dayHeaderFormat` hooks passes on arguments wrong date on `dayGridMonth` view, they always point to January 1970?

I am using fullcalendar version 5.11.3

Here is the code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    dayHeaderFormat: {
      weekday: "short",
      month: "numeric",
      day: "numeric",
      year: "numeric"
    },
    dayHeaderContent: function(arg) {
      console.log(arg.date.toISOString());
    }
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

[image]

Comment: How could they point to a specific date, do you imagine? A single column in the daygrid view covers multiple dates (all the ones vertically below it). So I imagine they just point to the day, and then have 1970 as the year because, being a date, they have to point to _something_. Anything else would be meaningless, or misleading at best. What result were you expecting, exactly?

Comment: I am expecting to point same date in the first row, do you see in the picture first box the date is 25 but in the header content its 4 January, so I am expecting first the year to be 2022, then the day to be 25, same on the other boxes in the first row?

Comment: @ADyson in the version 4 it's working like I said? https://codepen.io/DiarQoroviqi/pen/yLjZJgB check this link

Comment: Ok. Well the makers of fullCalendar must have changed it for v5 I guess. It makes more sense the way it is now IMHO - as I explained above, because then it's not appearing to refer to a specific date instead of a whole column...but if you don't like it you can maybe raise a feature request with them to add an option so you can ask it to behave like v4. https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features

Comment: Also, as an aside, why do you even want this? Surely the day of the week at the top, and the day number in the box (plus the month in the title bar) already explains what date each cell refers to. Why do you then need a date in the header which only refers to the first row of cells? Seems potentially confusing to the user, if you ask me. But of course that's just my opinion.